# How to pluralize two words in one sentence

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, forms, pluralize

I want to pluralize `"prohibio"` that is defined in my file `reflections.rb`:

```
ActiveSupport::Inflector.inflections(:en) do |inflect|
   inflect.irregular 'estadistica', 'estadisticas'
   inflect.irregular 'error', 'errores'
   inflect.irregular 'prohibio', "prohibieron"
  end
```

And this is my `_form.html.rb` file

```
<%= form_for(@estadistica) do |f| %>
  <% if @estadistica.errors.any? %>
    <div id="error_explanation">
      <h2><%= pluralize(@estadistica.errors.count, "error") %> prohibio esta temperatura de ser guardada:</h2>

      <ul>
      <% @estadistica.errors.full_messages.each do |message| %>
        <li><%= message %></li>
      <% end %>
      </ul>
    </div>
  <% end %>

  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :temperatura %><br>
    <%= f.text_field :temperatura %>
  </div>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :fecha %><br>
    <%= f.date_select :fecha %>
  </div>
  <div class="actions">
    <%= f.submit %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

Does anyone know how to pluralize two words?

Comment: (Does esta need to be pluralized to estan, too?)

Comment: You should pluralize the whole sentence, see http://guides.rubyonrails.org/i18n.html#pluralization

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, would this work:

```
<%= form_for(@estadistica) do |f| %>
  <% if @estadistica.errors.any? %>
    <div id="error_explanation">
      <h2><%= pluralize(@estadistica.errors.count, "error") %> <%= @estadistica.errors.count > 1 ? "prohibio".pluralize : "prohibio" %> esta temperatura de ser guardada:</h2>

      <ul>
      <% @estadistica.errors.full_messages.each do |message| %>
        <li><%= message %></li>
      <% end %>
      </ul>
    </div>
  <% end %>

  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :temperatura %><br>
    <%= f.text_field :temperatura %>
  </div>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :fecha %><br>
    <%= f.date_select :fecha %>
  </div>
  <div class="actions">
    <%= f.submit %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

Comment: no because it will print 1 error 1 prohibio and it should print = "1 error prohibio" , 2 errores prohibieron

Answer (score 0):

```
<%= form_for(@estadistica) do |f| %>
  <% if @estadistica.errors.any? %>
    <div id="error_explanation">
      <h2>  <% @errores_estadistica = @estadistica.errors.count %>
      <%= pluralize(@errores_estadistica, "error" ) %> 
      <% if @errores_estadistica > 1 %>
      <%= pluralize("", "prohibio") %> esta temperatura de ser guardada:
      <% else %>
          prohibio esta temperatura de ser guardada:
      <% end %>
      </h2>

      <ul>
      <% @estadistica.errors.full_messages.each do |message| %>
        <li><%= message %></li>
      <% end %>
      </ul>
    </div>
  <% end %>

  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :temperatura %><br>
    <%= f.text_field :temperatura %>
  </div>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :fecha %><br>
    <%= f.date_select :fecha %>
  </div>
  <div class="actions">
    <%= f.submit %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```